# ActionBar tabs without fragments?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

In my app I'm trying to use a custom ListView, found here:

http://www.hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-titles-icons-counter

and I can't load the models:

```
Adapter Release = new Adapter(this, generateData());

    // if extending Activity 2. Get ListView from activity_main.xml
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // 3. setListAdapter
    listView.setAdapter(Release);
}

private ArrayList<Model> generateData() {
    ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>();
    models.add(new Model("Group Title"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.action_help_32,"Menu Item 1","1"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.action_search_32,"Menu Item 2","2"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.collections_cloud_32,"Menu Item 3","12"));

    return models;
```

in the `onCreateView`

Is there a way to setup ActionBar tabs and change content, rather than fragments?

Comment: Can you provide more details on how are you setting data to adapter?

Comment: @Bapu I think this is what you meant? (I edited the code)

Answer (score 0):

You can set data to adapter dynamically. You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter after setting data.

Comment: So would this be called as my return values?

Comment: This call will rearrange your listview with new data.

Comment: I'm kind of a beginner.. So I think you're asking me to call my listview with notifyDataSetChanged() as a method?

Comment: Basically when your data changes, call setData on your adapter like, release.setData(models); release.notifyDataSetChanged();                 Make sure you follow standard java naming convention. So, it should be 'release' not 'Release'.

Comment: Okay. So, how would I find my listview in my onCreateView?